# How to rollback backbone.js model changes?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a "Cancel" button on my page which should reverts all the changes I made back to the state it was loaded from server..

I guess I need to store an initial state of Backbonejs model and restore a current (changed) state back to initial.

What is the best way to achieve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FWIW - i wrote a plugin to handle this automatically, specifically with the idea of "cancel" buttons in mind: http://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.memento

Comment: Thanks for the plugin. Is there a typo in this sentence (taken from the github page)? "Be sure to include the modelbinding file after the backbone.js file.", where modelbinding should read memento?

Comment: Is backbone.memento still usable in backbone 1.1? I see that the last commit has been in 2012.

Comment: it is! i still use it, and have an active project that i started a few weeks ago using it. :)

Comment: @DerickBailey also wrote a short but sweet post on the Decorator pattern, but it's in the context of implementing backbone.memento.   (Thanks Derick!) http://derickbailey.com/2014/09/09/decorating-a-backbone-model-with-features-for-a-ui-component/

Comment: @DerickBailey "oops! yeah, copy & paste error :P"   6 years later... same error still there :D

Answer (score 10):

`model.previousAttributes()` returns all of the previous attributes, while `model.changedAttributes()` returns all the changed attributes, but with their new values (or `false` if nothing has changed). So you could combine them to write a `cancelChanges` method in your prototype :

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    cancelChanges: function() {
        var changed = this.changedAttributes();

        if(!changed)
            return;

        var keys = _.keys(changed);
        var prev = _.pick(this.previousAttributes(), keys);

        this.set(prev, {silent: true}); // "silent" is optional; prevents change event
    },

});
```

Answer (score 8):

I dont believe there's a single method call for returning a model to its unedited state.. but the unedited values are available individually through model.previous(attribute) and collectively via model.previousAttributes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with:

```
var RollbackEnabledModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this._initAttributes = _.clone(this.attributes);
  },
  parse: function(data) {
    this._initAttributes = _.clone(data);
    return data;
  },
  rollback: function() {
    this.set(this._initAttributes);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NYTimes' [backbone.trackit](https://github.com/NYTimes/backbone.trackit). It tracks multiple changes to the model instead of only the most recent change like `model.changedAttributes()` and `model.previousAttributes()`.  From the README:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model({id:1, artist:'Samuel Beckett', 'work':'Molloy'});
model.startTracking();

model.set('work', 'Malone Dies');
console.log(model.unsavedAttributes());  // >> Object {work: "Malone Dies"}

model.set('period', 'Modernism');
console.log(model.unsavedAttributes());  // >> Object {work: "Malone Dies", period: "Modernism"}

model.save({}, {
    success: function() {
        console.log(model.unsavedAttributes());  // >> false
    }
});
```

> In addition, the library adds functionality to `resetAttributes` to
>   their original state since the last save, triggers an event when the
>   state of `unsavedChanges` is updated, and has options to opt into
>   prompting to confirm before routing to a new context.