# Undo view change after backbone sync fails

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm quite confused with backbone's view rendering. I need your help regarding this.

For example, I've a Album view. It's render method renders each Track view. All the track specific events are binding in the Track view.

Now, Track view is listening to it's model. For example:

```
this.model.on('destroy', this.destroy, this);

destroy: function(model){
    this.close();
},
```

so when a track is destroyed, the view is removed from UI which is fine. But problem is with sync. The view is removed from the UI not from server. If sync is successful, nothing to do with the view.

However, if the sync is not successful, I want to undo this view change (restore the track markup where it was before I destroyed it).

Can anyone please tell how can I do this?

FYI,
earlier I've altered the UI after getting success from server. But in more than 98% cases we get success, we decided to change the UI immediately and restore when there is an error.

Comment: Can you try specifying `{wait : true}` as said in the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) to wait for the server response to come back and then act accordingly ?

Comment: This is what we've used earlier but we want the UI to updated immediately.

Comment: But then how do you handle this scenario, like a model is destroyed from the client, including the view (without waiting for the server to respond), if the server fails, will you create the view for the deleted model again ?

Comment: this is the question is about.

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think its a good idea :-/

Comment: Derick Bailey to the rescue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7272262/793946

Answer (score 1):

There's a great plugin for dealing with this: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.memento

Answer (score 0):

I call view.remove() in the success callback of model.destroy, I think its easier to read the code and understand what happens that way.

But if you really want to restore the view on sync.error I guess you could call a restore method in an error callback from your destroy call. But it feels like more work to restore it than to wait for the ack.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to wait for getting success. I want to update immediately.